# NETLOGO: iterating over two lists of lists and dynamically changing items

Tags: netlogo, nested-lists

I am trying to build a model in Netlogo in which I have two lists of lists which I call offerlist and bidlist, the two list are structured as follows:

```
let offerlist [[offer_1 price_1 id_of_agent] [offer_2 price_2 id_of agent]...]
let bidlist [[bid_1 price_1 id_of_agent] [bid_2 price_2 id_of agent]...]
```

Basically every inner list contains the offer or bid of a certain agent, the price and the id of the agent submitting a certain offer/bid

I am trying to iterate over the two lists to simulate a market place, which means that I compare the prices of a certain offer and of a certain bid and if the conditions are met I would like to make a transaction happen reducing the offer in the offerlist and the bid in the bidlist.
To be more specific I tried to do it like this:

```
to-report replace-subitem [index1 index2 lists value]
  let old-sublist item index1 lists 
  report replace-item index1 lists (replace-item index2 old-sublist value)
end

foreach offerlist[[x]->
   foreach bidlist[[y]->
     if item 1 x < item 1 y[
       set bidlist replace-subitem (position y bidlist) 0 bidlist 0
       set offerlist replace-subitem (position x offerlist) 0 offerlist 0
]
]
]
```

The replace-subitem reporter works when it comes to change items of inner lists of a list of lists and I found it on Stack Overflow.
Unfortunately using this I get an error since instead of the index of the items of the list I get a TRUE/FALSE probably because it is not possible or not functional to change items of the lists while I iterate through them.
Is there a way to iterate through the lists while modifying the elements if certain conditions are met? If so which is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you give a small example of actual input lists and example expected output for those lists? I'm not quite certain what you're after.

Comment: @LukeC An example of input list would be: offerlist [[25 15 1]...] bidlist [[15 20 2]...]
when these two lists are compared the price of the bid is higher than the price of the offer so a transaction can happen so the output lists would become:
offerlist[[10 15 1]...] bidlist [[0 20 2]...]. This because the bid of 15 units is completely satisfied by the offer of 25 units which is then reduced to 10 units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the comment- One way to do this would be to use `foreach` with indices rather than with the list items directly, so you can use the index from one list to refer to another. With this setup:

```
globals [ offerlist bidlist ]

to setup
  ca
  set offerlist [ [ 25 15 1 ] [ 75 25 2 ] [ 23 35 3 ] ]
  set bidlist   [ [ 15 20 1 ] [ 90 30 2 ] [ 20 40 3 ] ] 
  reset-ticks
end
```

Then (assuming the lists are always the same length) you can use the length of whichever list to build indices and iterate over every one. More detail in comments:

```
to update-lists
  foreach range ( length offerlist ) [
    ind ->
    ; Get the first items from each current sublist
    let offer-item item ind offerlist
    let bid-item item ind bidlist

    ; If the offer is greater than the bid, get the
    ; difference between those values
    if first offer-item > first bid-item [
      let dif first offer-item - first bid-item

      ; Update the offer item with the difference value
      set offer-item replace-item 0 offer-item dif

      ; Update the bid-item with 0  
      set bid-item replace-item 0 bid-item 0

      ; Go back to the index value to update both the
      ; offerlist and the bidlist
      set offerlist replace-item ind offerlist offer-item
      set bidlist replace-item ind bidlist bid-item
    ]
  ]

  print offerlist
  print bidlist
end
```

Which takes you from the input lists that look like:

```
[[25 15 1] [75 25 2] [23 35 3]]
[[15 20 1] [90 30 2] [20 40 3]]
```

to the output of:

```
[[10 15 1] [75 25 2] [3 35 3]]
[[0 20 1] [90 30 2] [0 40 3]]
```

If you'd prefer a `map` version, I *think* you have to do it in two steps:

```
to update-lists-map 
  ; Make a temporary offerlist by mapping over
  ; the current offerlist and bidlist, and replacing
  ; the first item as appropriate
  let newoffers ( map [ 
    [ o_ b_ ] -> 
    ifelse-value ( first o_ > first b_) 
    [ replace-item 0 o_ ( first o_ - first b_ )]
    [ o_ ]
  ] offerlist bidlist )

  ; Make a temporary bidlist by mapping over
  ; the current offerlist and bidlist, and zeroing
  ; the first item as appropriate
  let newbids ( map [ 
    [ o_ b_ ] -> 
    ifelse-value ( first o_ > first b_) 
    [ replace-item 0 b_ 0 ]
    [ b_ ]
  ] offerlist bidlist )

  ; overwrite the original offer and bid lists
  set offerlist newoffers
  set bidlist newbids

  print offerlist
  print bidlist
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think of iterarting through the indices of the lists instead of the elements of the list itself. That was a very useful insight.